# PWA/Web: Remember file system access permissions on app restart

Tags: web, permissions, upload, progressive-web-apps, resume

i am looking for a way to resume file uploads after session restart.

Is there a way (like in PWA API) to let the browser sth. like remember the access permissions granted to read files (and upload them), so that if the user closes the session and reopens it, the file upload can be continued?